# SVG Filters Turn Off My CSS Filters. Why?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, filter

Stepping through my page, this line of code turns off my SVG Filter:

```
if (document.getElementById("cPreview") != null) document.getElementById("cPreview").style.filter =  "brightness(" + parseInt(percentB) + "%)" + " contrast(" + parseInt(percentC) + "%)" +  " saturate(" + parseInt(percentS) + "%)";
```

If I add SVG code to that, my CSS Filters are turned off:

```
if (document.getElementById("cPreview") != null) document.getElementById("cPreview").style.filter = svgCOLOR + "brightness(" + parseInt(percentB) + "%)" + " contrast(" + parseInt(percentC) + "%)" +  " saturate(" + parseInt(percentS) + "%)";
```

How do I code that so the SVG Filter and the CSS Filters play nicely together?

Thank you

---

Someone asked for an example. Here is the original image:

[image]

Here is the image with the CSS Filters applied:

[image]

Here is the image with the SVG Filter applied:

[image]

Here is the image with all filters applied.  I had to make this in a photo editor because that one line of code isn't working.  It all comes down to that one line of code posted above.  I can make CSS work, or make SVG work, but I cannot make both work together. Thank you

[image]

Comment: `.style` is CSS so those are both being applied to the CSS filters. You're overwriting the previous filters each time you set it.

Comment: What is `svgCOLOR`? If it isn't a valid part of a complete filter string, the whole thing won't work.

Comment: The SVG Filter is <feColorMatrix> it works fine.  I just can' t get the CSS Filters and the SVG Filter to work together.  It's one or the other working, never both.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] i.e. we want to be able to run something ourselves and see what you're seeing.

Comment: That will take some time, I certainly can't do it right now, I'm caring for a sick relative.  In a nutshell, what I see is simple: an image with the CSS Filters applied or an image with the SVG Filter applied.  I'll see if I can edit the original question to show this.

Comment: Thank you, but the images aren't really helpful here.  We need to see the code. Especially what the value of `svgCOLOR` is.  It needs to be something like" `url(#MyFilter)"`. Note also that you need ensure there is a space between your filter reference, and the rest of the values (ie. `svgCOLOR + " brightness("`...).